# Метод прямоугольника не параллелится

Tags: c++, openmp, численные-методы

Здравствуйте пишу простой алгоритм численного метода (прямоугольника). Распараллелил эту функцию с помощью OpenMP. Но время выполнения параллельного алгоритма больше, чем выполнение с одним поток. В чем ошибка?  Использую пк с 12 ядрами процессора,999999999 итераций.

```
const unsigned long numSteps=999999999;                     /* default # of rectangles */
const double PI25DT = 3.141592653589793238462643;
double function(double x) //Подынтегральная функция
{
  return 4.0/(1.+ x*x); //Например, sin(x)
}

double CalcIntegralWithParallel(int countThread) {
   double x, pi = 0;
   double sum=0.0;
   double step = 1./static_cast<double>(numSteps);
 #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(countThread) reduction(+:sum)
    for (int i=0; i<numSteps; i++)
    {
        x = (i + .5)*step;
        sum = sum + function(x);
    }
    pi = sum*step;
    return pi;
}

double CalcIntegral(double a, double b) {
    double x, pi = 0;

    double sum=0.0;
    double step =1./static_cast<double>(numSteps);
    for (int i=0; i<numSteps; i++)
    {
        x = (i + .5)*step;
        sum = sum + function(x);
    }
    pi = sum*step;
    return pi;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    double timeStart ,timeStop;
    double pi; 
    double secs;

    timeStart = omp_get_wtime();
    pi = CalcIntegral(8,0);
    timeStop = omp_get_wtime();
    std::cout << "The value of integral is " << pi << " Error is " << fabs(pi - PI25DT) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The time to calculate integral was " ;
    secs=  timeStop - timeStart;
    std::cout << secs << " seconds\n" << std::endl;

    timeStart = omp_get_wtime();
    pi = CalcIntegralWithParallel(4);
    timeStop = omp_get_wtime();
    std::cout << "The value of PI is OPEN MP 4 " << pi << " Error is " << fabs(pi - PI25DT) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The time to calculate PI was " ;
    secs=  timeStop - timeStart;
    std::cout << secs << " seconds\n" << std::endl;

    timeStart = omp_get_wtime();
    pi = CalcIntegralWithParallel(8);
    timeStop = omp_get_wtime();
    std::cout << "The value of PI is OPEN MP 8 " << pi << " Error is " << fabs(pi - PI25DT) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The time to calculate PI was " ;
     secs=  timeStop - timeStart;
    std::cout << secs << " seconds\n" << std::endl;

    timeStart = omp_get_wtime();
    pi = CalcIntegralWithParallel(12);
    timeStop = omp_get_wtime();
    std::cout << "The value of PI is OPEN MP 12 " << pi << " Error is " << fabs(pi - PI25DT) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The time to calculate PI was " ;
     secs=  timeStop - timeStart;
    std::cout << secs << " seconds\n" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Ниже результат выполнения программы:**

> The value of integral is 3.14159 Error is 7.54952e-15 The time to
>   calculate integral was 11.9711 seconds
>
> The value of PI is OPEN MP 4 3.14162 Error is 2.64888e-05 The time to
>   calculate PI was 20.342 seconds
>
> The value of PI is OPEN MP 8 3.14159 Error is 3.7927e-07 The time to
>   calculate PI was 21.1447 seconds
>
> The value of PI is OPEN MP 12 3.14162 Error is 3.16601e-05 The time to
>   calculate PI was 21.4869 seconds

Comment: Тут что-то странное... Я просто собрал Вашу программу у себя на gcc (mingw-w64 7.3  x86). Ну, добавил заголовков. Все работает. И на вид - все адекватно.  The value of integral is 3.14159 Error is 1.77636e-015
The time to calculate integral was 5.226 seconds

The value of PI is OPEN MP 4 3.14159 Error is 1.66533e-013
The time to calculate PI was 1.498 seconds

The value of PI is OPEN MP 8 3.14159 Error is 6.92779e-014
The time to calculate PI was 1.139 seconds

The value of PI is OPEN MP 12 3.14159 Error is 9.4591e-014
The time to calculate PI was 1.264 seconds

Comment: К числам добавлю, это было запущено на CPU Intel Core i5 Haswell, 4 честных ядра (без HT). Да, по-хорошему, при записи директив для OpenMP надо было бы еще раздать роли (у Вас там переменная `x` в цикле просит указать ей что-то типа *firstprivate*). Но результат похож на правду и без этого...

Comment: @Vladimir оно автоматически должно определять

Comment: @Vladimir проверка была на 12 ядровом компе

Comment: @МаксимСавельев, и что? 12 ядер работают медленнее моих 4-х? 20 секунд??? Это что же за архитектура? Какой-то навороченный ARM? И что там должно автоматически определять? роли? - так оно только простейшие случаи умеет, например, как индекс цикла.

Comment: собираешь то точно с openmp?

Comment: @Fat-Zer да....

Comment: это было ненавящевое предложение рассказать о своей платформе и как собираешь т.к. в приведённом коде проблем нет... разве что отсутствие хедеров...

Comment: @Fat-Zer собираю в терминале Ubuntu g++ -fopenmp main.cpp -o main
 
получаю файл main
 
./main - запуск

Comment: @Vladimir а какие зависимости ты писал?

Comment: @МаксимСавельев, да самый минимум, что попросило...

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <omp.h>

using namespace std;

Сборка: `g++ omp.cpp -o o -Ofast -fopenmp`. Еще попробовал в x64: `g++ omp.cpp -o o -Ofast -fopenmp -static -m64`. Общий результат тот же, только еще раза в 2 быстрее.

Answer (score 3):

В общем, как я и говорил, все дело в роли для `x`. Если программу оставить как есть, то тогда при оптимизации `gcc` все делает правильно сам, а без оптимизации для `x` отводится роль общей переменной для потоков (`shared` - я проверил, установив эту роль для `x`). Из-за этого получается неверный результат (очень низкая точность) и коллизии при попытке нескольких потоков одновременно записать в эту `x`. Лечится принудительным указанием, что `x` должна быть приватной для каждого потока (лучше через `firstprivate`, чтобы она унаследовала и начальное значение, но это уже не так важно в данной задаче).

Такая прагма решает проблему при неоптимизированной сборке `g++ omp.cpp -o o  -fopenmp`:

```
 #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(countThread) reduction(+:sum) firstprivate(x)
```

У меня на i5 Haswell (4 ядра) получились следующие результаты:

- The value of integral is 3.14159 Error is 2.05835e-012
  The time to calculate integral was **16.973** seconds
- The value of PI is OPEN MP **4** 3.14159 Error is 3.55715e-013
  The time to calculate PI was **4.556** seconds
- The value of PI is OPEN MP **8** 3.14159 Error is 1.24345e-013
  The time to calculate PI was **4.321** seconds
- The value of PI is OPEN MP **12** 3.14159 Error is 1.22125e-013
  The time to calculate PI was **4.415** seconds

что является вполне нормальным на мой взгляд.

Comment: мда... очевидная ошибка... даже неловко, что просмотрел... только `firstprivate` здесь бессмысленно, а обычного `private` более чем достаточно... ЗЫ: [Правила присвоения контекстов по-умолчанию](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.cbcpx01/cuppvars.htm)

Comment: @Fat-Zer, я и написал, что для этой задачи и просто private сойдет. Написал "лучше", чтобы перед назначением в подобных задачах подумали... и на мой взгляд, firstprivate не ухудшает ситуацию (а просто private - очень даже может)... А в заблуждение ввело то, что оптимизатор все сам исправил, поэтому я сначала и подумал, что все хорошо...